# unable to click the radio button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click, radio-button

i want to click a one-way radio button of the spice jet book a flight page .i wrote the below code in web driver format but button unable to click

```
public void flight() throws Exception{   
        driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/FlyForSure.aspx");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.AvailabilitySearchInputCompactSearchVi_OneWay")).click();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     spice a1=new spice();
     a1.flight();
}

}
```

Error message;

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input.AvailabilitySearchInputCompactSearchView_OneWay"}
Command duration or timeout: 15.96 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

There is frame so you need to switch frame using  below code :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

Add above code before line of cod to select radio button